# Avoid dependency in Integration Testing

Tags: testing, automation, testng

In integration testing scenario, I have an object creation if the object creation is successful I have Record CRUD operation but if object creation fails then record operation should be skipped. To maintain these integration scenarios I have configured my testng.xml file like this : -

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestNG" verbose="1" >

    <test name="Object  Testing" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.settings.test.employee.PostObject" />
            <class name="com.settings.test.employee.GetObject" />
            <class name="com.settings.test.employee.DeleteObject" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name=" Record Testing" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.settings.test.employee.PostObject" />
            <class name="com.settings.test.employee.PostRecord" />
            <class name="com.settings.test.employee.GetRecord" />
            <class name="com.settings.test.employee.GetRecordByID" />
            <class name="com.settings.test.employee.DeleteObject" />
        </classes>
    </test>


</suite>
```

In this approach unneccessary i am doing the same operation again and again which increases time of execution and code size.
I need to maintain this dependency at a class level not outside of the class, please suggest me some approach on how I can make it happen?.

Answer (score 0):

Please use dependsOnGroups or dependsOnMethods so that you can control when it will be executed.

You can use below links as an example

https://www.journaldev.com/21389/testng-dependency-dependsonmethods-dependsongroups

Comment: but again that class have to look for  its dependent class or method in some other class. I want to remove this scenario.